# Valuation Rings of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Question : What are the valuation rings of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I have started reading some Algebraic Geometry from Daniel Bump's book. I don't really have much background in commutative algebra (hence the choice of this particular book as it's more self contained in that sense). This is Exercise 2.2 from the book.

The definition given for valuation ring $R$ of a field $F$ is that $R$ is a subring of $F$ such that $x\in F\setminus\{0\}$ implies $x\in R$ or $x^{-1}\in R$. I also know that valuation rings are local.

It is easy to see that subrings of the form $\{a/b\in \mathbb{Q}\; |\; p\nmid b\}$ (for $p$ primes) are valuation rings of $\mathbb{Q}$. So the question boils down to whether rings like these exhaust all valuation rings of $\mathbb{Q}$? My guess is Yes they do. Is there a direct(elementary) way to show this?

Comment: Let $R$ be your valuation ring. You have the usual valuation $v:\mathbb{Q}^\times\to \mathbb{Q}^\times/R^\times$. What about looking at the set of integers with positive valuation?

Comment: As I have said, I have not studied valuation theory in any previous commutative algebra course. I wish to prove it with the data given in Bump's book which I have mentioned in my question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @NicolaiKunz You might be interested in skimming the wiki on [Ostrowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, because the valuation rings in a field are also characterised by the  property that they are maximal subrings among local subrings for the *domination* relation (i.e. the maximal ideal of the smaller ring is contained in the maximal ideal of the larger ring).

*Some more details*: any subring $V\subset\mathbf Q$ contains $\mathbf Z$, and if $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of $V$, $\mathfrak m\cap\mathbf Z $ is generated by a prime $p$ and clearly $\mathbf Z_{(p)}$ is dominated by $V$. As it is also a valuation ring, by maximality, we have $\mathbf Z_{(p)}=V$.

Comment: The general result is: let $A$ be a PID and $K$ its field of fractions. The valuation rings of $K$ containing $A$ and distinct from $K$ are the rings of the form $A_{pA}$, where $p\in A$ is prime (Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. VI, 1.4, Proposition 3).